# Active Directory pass-through authentication

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

Is Active Directory pass-through authentication available on "AD on-premise (Windows Server 2016)" or only on Azure AD?

EDIT:
We have different network segments/zones. In the DMZ we have an AD domain for external users and on the internal zone we have an AD domain for our internal users. Also each zone is divided in three layers (Access, Application and Data).
AD's is in Data layer.

Now we plan to setup an OpenID Connect/OAuth2 provider (Identity & Access Management) in DMZ and would like to authenticate users in both AD's.
Firewall team does not want to open firewalls from Application layer in DMZ to Data layer in Internal zone. It should be ok to open between zones in the same layer.

As commented below the pass-through is only available in Azure AD.

I then mainly see two options:
Replicate users from Internal AD to 
 1. Replicate users from Internal AD to DMZ AD (as read-only)
 2. Use ADFS to aggregate from both AD's

Disclaimer: I am not very knowledgeable in AD/ADFS :)

Comment: Pass through authentication is an AAD feature. What are you looking to do? If you only have on-prem AD, then you get SSO if your app uses Integrated Windows Authentication and the client has visibility to domain controller.

Comment: Hi @juunas , thanks for your comment. I have updated the first post with some more info